# Verilog - incrementing variable using buttons

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I'm actually trying for 3 days to make my code works. I have an dev board with multiplexed 7-seg display - it's working. The problem is, when I'm trying to increment a variable. I written code below:

```
assign buttons =  debouncedL  | debouncedR;

always @(posedge buttons or negedge RES) begin
    if(~RES) number <= 0;
    else if(debouncedL) number <= (number + 10);
    else if(debouncedR) number <= (number + 1);
end
```

And it's not working. When I'm pressing R button, variable is incremented by 1, but when I'm pressing L nothing happens. After changing positions of both `else if`, L button still not work and displayed number is toggling between 0000 and 0001 after pressing R button. It might be newbie question, but I can't find solution in book and on Internet. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is `number` defined?

Comment: This is: `reg [13:0] number;`

Comment: How is your FPGA toolkit actually implementing this? I'm drawn to think that your odd trigger logic might be making it more difficult to synthesize this than a synchronous design.

Comment: You mean this? http://i.imgur.com/CbOXAmj.png
Red line is debouncedL. DebouncedR is the second line entering OR gate.

Comment: And this is version from code posted (where else if with L button is first): http://i.imgur.com/nzTUOtR.png

Comment: Offhand, the schematics appear correct. Based on the schematic, it looks like you're debouncing the buttons yourself - Are the buttons on the devboard not already debounced? Are you sure your debouncing logic is correct?

Comment: This board doesn't have hardware debounced buttons. Debouncing logic is correct, I checked it using logic analyzer. When I was using only one button everything worked perfectly.
Here is the entire code: http://pastebin.com/Jj9U5RQL
Maybe something else is wrong. I'm beginner, so this is possible.

Comment: I've made a little change in code. Replaced debouncedL and debouncedR by L and R (negated of course) in if statements and it's working. But why? I don't understand this. I know why it's working now, but I haven't any idea why it wasn't working before, cause I think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is asynchronous, you have [metastability on buttons](https://embeddedmicro.com/tutorials/mojo/metastability-and-debouncing) signal.

In synchronous design (and all FPGA design should be synchronous) only clock can be used for **always @posedge()** process. In your design you are using button signal as a clock.

To detect raising edge on button you have to save the old state of button signal and compare it to current state like this :

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge rst) begin
    // detect rising edge
    if (button_old != button && button == 1'b1)
          button_raise <= 1'b1
    button_old <= button;
    // increment number
    if(button_raise == 1b'1)
    begin
        if(~RES) number <= 0;
        else if(debouncedL) number <= (number + 10);
        else if(debouncedR) number <= (number + 1);
    end
end
```